# What does the 500 telemetry data points per second limit actually mean in Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

On [this documentation page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics/#limits) there is the following limitation of Application Insights documented:

> Up to 500 telemetry data points per second per instrumentation key (that is, per application). This includes both the standard telemetry sent by the SDK modules, and custom events, metrics and other telemetry sent by your code.

However it doesn't explain what the implications of that limit are?

a) Does it buffer and throttle, but still persist all data eventually? So say - 1000 data points get pushed within a second - it will persist the first 500, then wait for a bit and push the other 500?

*or*

b) Does it just drop/not log data? So say - 1000 data points get pushed within a second and only the first 500 will be persisted and the other 500 not (ever)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the latter (b) with the caveat that ALL data will start to be throttled in this case, i.e. once RPC is > 500 (100 for free apps, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-data-retention-privacy/ for details) is detected, it will start rejecting all data from this instrumentation key on data collection endpoint, until RPC rate is back to under 500.

*EDIT: Further information from Bret Grinslade:*

The current implementation averages over one minute -- so if you send 30K in 1 minute (500*60) it will throttle your application. The HTTP response will tell the SDK to retry later. If the incoming rate never comes down, the response will tell the SDK to drop the data. We are working on other features to improve this experience -- pre-aggregation on the client, improved burst data rates, etc.

Comment: @BretGrinslade  Just to clarify - is the limit on number of calls to the API endpoints or number or number of data items sent in a batch?

Comment: I added a suggestion on the uservoice website at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/13804695-remove-500-telemetry-data-points-per-second-limita

Any news on the improvements on the experience?

Answer (score 3):

A bit more detail on top of Alex's response.  The current implementation averages over one minue -- so if you send 30K in 1 minute (500*60) it will throttle your application. The HTTP response will tell the SDK to retry later.  If the incoming rate never comes down, the response will tell the SDK to drop the data.  We are working on other features to improve this experience -- pre-aggregation on the client, improved burst data rates, etc.

Comment: Thanks for additional information. I have merged it into Alex's answer with a comment that it is coming from you, so that all info is there.

Answer (score 0):

AI now has the ingestion throttling limit of 16K EPS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-pricing

Comment: This has been updated again to 32 K events per second. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-pricing